# Access import declarations of IType

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

Is there a good way to access the import declarations of an IType, without manually searching through the source code one can get as a `String` with `getSource()`?

**Example**:
If the IType is this Java class in a source file:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList; 

public class MyClass {
    // some content
}
```

I want to retrieve `[java.util.Arrays, java.util.HashSet, java.util.LinkedList]`. Whether the imported types are retrieved as Strings or ITypes or something else is not really important for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the various models of JDT, the **Java Model** (of which `IType` is a part) is the most light-weight one. As a consequence it doesn't have the information you are seeking. Only the **AST** has this information, available as `CompilationUnit.imports()`.
For an introduction to JDT's AST see, e.g., the tutorial slides ["How To Train the JDT Dragon"](http://www.eclipsecon.org/2012/sites/eclipsecon.org.2012/files/How%20To%20Train%20the%20JDT%20Dragon%20combined.pdf) (Slide 31ff).

At a first glance for the task at hand getting the full AST may appear to be overkill, but at least it correctly handles (skips) all comments that might come before / between imports.

Comment: What are the advantages of the Java model being so light-weight? Is the Java model faster than the Java AST?

Comment: Yes, the Java Model is designed to quickly work on the entire content of your workspace. By contrast, the AST is typically used for one type at a time.